# Unity3D - How to "force" rotation over the X axis

Tags: unity

When I click to left or right, up or down, I'd like my airplane to rotate over the x-axis, to loop, and at some point over the z-axis in order to end up with the y-axis pointing up (world up).

Let me show you what it looks like right now, and draw what I'd like the end result to be like.

Up and down:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/HFqRychpR9W8oFq59

Right and left:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/BcPyQvu2TFpG763aA

This is what I'd like to happen:

[image]

Here is how the axis are setup
[image]

Here is the code that is currently rotating the airplane

```
    void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        worldposition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 57));
        worldposition.z = 25;
        relativePos = worldposition - transform.position;
    }

    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, rotation, RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, 25);

}
```

I have played around with Rotation and Quaternions for a few days already and I am unable to accomplish what I need.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried and what is the current result?

Comment: I have tried using Transform Rotation, Quaternion rotation, and the current result is what you see in the video links I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flight maneuver you are describing is an [Immelmann Turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immelmann_turn#Aerobatic_maneuver) followed by a descent back to the original flight level. This maneuver has 5 distinct phases:

1. pitch 180° up
2. roll 180°
3. pitch 30° down
4. fly forward for a short time
5. pitch 30° up

As you can see, this is a multi-step process where each step performs a different rotate motion. So you can not implement it with a single rotation.

If you insist on using a code-based solution, then you will have to use a state-machine. Have your update-method keep track of which phase of the maneuver it is in and then perform the action relevant for that phase.

However what I would recommend instead is to use the [animation system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationSection.html). The system can do a lot more than just moving the legs of character models. You can create animations which manipulate (almost) every property of every component of a game object over a timeframe, including position and rotation. That means you can describe the motion you want your game object to perform using curves in a visual editor. This even allows you to tweak the animation in real-time.
[image]

The Unity animation system is a really powerful tool, but it is also complex. Describing it from the beginning would be far too long for the scope of this answer. But it shouldn't be hard to find some basic tutorials or to learn it from the documentation I linked above.

Comment: I knew that my question would not have a simple answer because I've been trying for a while to get this right. I was really looking for someone to point me into the right direction, and I think you have done just that with these two options. I will try the code base solution since I am much more comfortable with that, but if it takes the animation system it looks like a good excuse to do dive deep into it. Appreciate the links and the insightful information